# What is the probability that for any $9$ randomly chosen apples, $3$ of the apples will be rejected?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**STATEMENT:** At a food processing plant, the best apples are bagged to be sold in grocery stores. The remaining apples are either thrown out if damaged or used in food products if not appealing enough to be bagged and sold. If apples are randomly chosen for a special inspection, the probability is $0.2342$ that the $3rd$ rejected apple will be the $9th$ apple randomly chosen.

**QUESTION:** What is the probability that for any $9$ randomly chosen apples, $3$ of the apples will be rejected?

**MY WORKING:**

If we let rejected apple to be $success$ then data suggests that $r = 3rd$ $Successs$ to occur on $x = 9th$ trial has probability $0.2342$, which is problem involving Negative Binomial Distribution. By using its probability distribution we have: $f(x)={x-1 \choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{x-r}$

By putting values of $r=3$, $x=9, f(x=9)=0.2342$, and solving for $p$ we get its value. From here on, I am not sure how to tackle the question to answer required result.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What value of $p$ did you get? Using that value of $p$, you can easily find the probability that for any $9$ randomly chosen apples, $3$ of the apples will be rejected using the binomial distribution.  But there is a faster way that does not need $p$

Comment: Thanks I can take it from here. As for value of $p$, I didn't solve it explicitly. I am stuck at $0.0083=p^3(1−p)^6.$ Can I solve it explicity from here, or do I have to use software ?

Comment: There is a slight problem: $p^3(1−p)^6 \le \frac{2^6}{3^9} \approx 0.00325$  with equality when $p=\frac13$ so there is no solution in $[0,1]$

Comment: $0.0083=p^3(1−p)^6$ has a real solution of about $p\approx 1.3826669$ as well as complex solutions,  but this is not meaningful as $p$ is supposed to be the probability of a bad apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is actually impossible, but here is a solution which ignores that:

- you have said the negative binomial probability that  the $3$rd rejected apple will be the $9$th apple randomly chosen is ${x-1 \choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{x-r}$
- similarly the binomial probability that that for any $9$ randomly chosen apples $3$ of the apples will be rejected is ${x \choose r}p^r(1-p)^{x-r}$
- dividing the latter by the former gives $\frac xr=3$ so the answer should be $3\times 0.2342 = 0.7026$

But this is all nonsense:  $p^r(1-p)^{x-r}$ and any positive constant multiple of it is maximised with $p \in [0,1]$ when $p=\frac rx$ which is $\frac13$ here, so the negative binomial probability cannot exceed $28\frac{2^6}{3^9} \approx 0.09105$ contrary to the the question and the binomial probability cannot exceed $84\frac{2^6}{3^9} \approx 0.27313$ contrary to the answer.

Comment: The question is in the past papers of the course I am studying. How they can give a question which has no solution at all. May be the approach I am taking isn't correct. There has to be answer.

Comment: If I consider your answer, how did you arrived at the answer by multiplying $\frac{x}{r}=3$ with $0.2342$. Can you define the logic in this step?

Comment: ${x \choose r}p^r(1-p)^{x-r} =\frac xr \times {x-1 \choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{x-r}$ since $\frac{x!}{r!(x-r)!} = \frac xr \times \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)!(x-r)!}  = \frac xr \times  {x-1 \choose r-1}$

Comment: I know this. I am asking about the part "the answer should be $3×0.2342=0.7026$." what is the logic behind this multipication to arrive at the required answer of $0.7026.$?

Comment: That is the logic.  You "know" the value of ${x-1 \choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{x-r}=0.2342$ so you multiply it by $\frac xr=3$ to get  ${x \choose r}p^r(1-p)^{x-r}$ which is what you want to find

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ is probability that randomly chosen apple will be rejected, $P(k,n)$ is probability that among first $k$ randomly chosen $k$ apples will be exactly $n$ rejected, $Q(k,n)$ is probability that $n$-th rejected apple will be $k$-th randomly chosen apple.
$$P(k,n)=P(k-1,n-1)p+P(k-1,n)(1-p), P(0,0)=1, P(0,m>0)=0$$
Solution of this recurrence is $$P(k,n)=\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!} p^n (1-p)^{k-n}$$
$$Q(k,n)=P(k-1,n-1)p=\frac{(k-1)!}{(n-1)!(k-n)!} p^{n-1} (1-p)^{k-n} p$$
$$\frac{P(k,n)}{Q(k,n)}=\frac{\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!} p^n (1-p)^{k-n}}{\frac{(k-1)!}{(n-1)!(k-n)!} p^{n-1} (1-p)^{k-n} p}=\frac{k!}{(k-1)!}\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{k}{n}$$
$$P(k,n)=\frac{k}{n} Q(k,n)$$
$$P(9,3)=\frac{9}{3} Q(9,3)=3Q(9,3)$$

But situation described in question is impossible, because $Q(9,3)$ cannot be equal 0.2342:

$$Q(9,3)=\frac{8!}{2!\cdot 6!}p^3 (1-p)^6=28 (p(1-p)^2)^3$$

Using AM-GM for $0 \leq p \leq 1$:

$$p(1-p)^2 =\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2p\cdot (1-p)\cdot (1-p) \leq \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{2p+
(1-p)+(1-p)}{3}\right)^3=\frac{4}{27}$$
$$Q(9,3) \leq 28 \cdot\left(\frac{4}{27}\right)^3=\frac{1792}{19683}<\frac{1}{10}$$